# I can't sum the numbers of a nested loop. TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I would like to sum all the `item` elements and get the result `18`, but I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The problem is that I cannot sum the values_subtraction_average values which are: 5.0, 0.0, -4.0, 4.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0. So I think the problem is the second loop.

[image]

The goal is to use the first loop to subtract each individual value from the mean and get 5.0, 0.0, -4.0, 4.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0. Next, in the second loop, i would like to sum all the results of values_subtraction_average and get the result `18`. How can i solve the problem? What line of code would I need?

Code:

```
values = [29, 24, 20, 28, 22, 22, 23]
average = sum(values) / len(values)

for single_value in values:
    values_subtraction_average = single_value - average
    # >>> 5.0, 0.0, -4.0, 4.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0.

    for item in range(values_subtraction_average):
        x = sum(float(item))
```

Comment: `sum(float(item))` does not make sense. What is the sum of a number?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think the mistake is here. I would just like to get something else. I would like to sum all the values_subtraction_average which are 5.0, 0.0, -4.0, 4.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0. The result is 18: I would like to get 18 in the second loop

Comment: @Nonsaprei the result is 0 not 18 ?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I've updated the question, adding a link of a secure image uploaded to StackOverflow (I'm new and can't add images directly). In the image you can see how and why I get 18.

Comment: Ah, you're supposed to add the absolute values of the differences.

Comment: Where the code says `for item in range(values_subtraction_average):`, what do you think this means? What do you think will be the value of `item` each time through the loop, and what type do you think it should have? Why? Step by step, what is the intended logic of the code - how will it calculate the sum that you want?

Comment: As you have seen, they closed my answer. I've added more clarity and detail to the question. Can you reopen it again please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
values = [29, 24, 20, 28, 22, 22, 23]

x = sum(values) / len(values)
y = sum(abs(v - x) for v in values)
print(y)

print(y / len(values))
```

Prints:

```
18.0
2.5714285714285716
```

Comment: Only now I realize that, with your code, I get an error regarding the line x = sum(values) / len(values). The error is TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable. How can I solve it? :)

Comment: @Nonsaprei You've probably assigned to `sum` or `len` variable (don't use variable names same as python built-ins)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the total of the differences of the values from the mean, you could loop over the values and calculate the difference, and then add this difference to a separate total variable, like so:

```
values = [29, 24, 20, 28, 22, 22, 23]
average = sum(values) / len(values)

total = 0

for single_value in values:
    values_subtraction_average = single_value - average
    # >>> 5.0, 0.0, -4.0, 4.0, -2.0, -2.0, -1.0.
    total += abs(values_subtraction_average)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the `total` variable store the `abs(values_subtraction_average)`

```py
values = [29, 24, 20, 28, 22, 22, 23]
average = sum(values) / len(values)
total = 0
for single_value in values:
    values_subtraction_average = single_value - average
    total += abs(values_subtraction_average)
print(total)  
#18
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35197453)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine Maybe you did not understand what was required